# How to Reconnect the location client(Fused location) in onActivityResult

Tags: android

For retriving user current location aim using the new Fused location provided by Google recently and got the current location.but when my app is not enable any location services and it takes to the location settings page and select a particular location service in onActivityResult the mLocationClient is not reconnect and app crashes please help how to reconnect the location client

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke :

```
if (!mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }
```

and then wait connection is done in :

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    startPeriodicUpdates();

}
```